# How do machines understand that 1 means on and 0 means off?

Tags: binary

I have been working with coding for a couple of months now (I'm still not very knowlegable though), and I have recently thought of something that confuses me. I understand that machines read "1" as on and "0" as off, but who originally told them to read it that way? How would one tell a machine that numbers mean power, and couldn't that person just have easily said that "5" means on and "pi" means off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the other way around really. "Power" or electric charge is what drives computers (CPU, volatile memory, storage, displays and so on). In most devices, 2 state electrical components are used to construct a functional, usage device (such as a hard drive). These components "understand" 2 different levels of electrical charge that are logically equivalent to 1's & 0's, but this logical meaning exists only in our interpretation of the actual (physical) behavior of computer systems.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much "on" and "off" as it is `true` and `false`. A bit is the basic unit of information and can have two values (which is why we call it binary). It is physically implemented as a two-state device (e.g. does something have power or doesn't it? Is there water in the bucket or isn't there?). A computer has a bunch of these bits which are either 1 (true) if a certain physical state is present or 0 (false) if it is not.  For more info I'd recommend checking out the wikipedia page on bits: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit